# SimpleComboBox in GXT

Tags: gxt

How to use key/value pair using SimpleComboBox in GXT. I'm able to add a key to SimpleComboBox but how to add value of a particular key to a SimpleComboBox? 
Later I want to retrieve value of key.
Thanks & Regards,
Anand

Comment: Is key and value should appear symaltaneously on SimpleComboBOX

Comment: Why not using the ComboBox?, using the ModelData you can define you key and value fields.

Comment: @Anand You should always specify GXT version you are using. There has been a lot of changes from GXT 2 to GXT 3. Answer of `RadAsm` is for GXT 3, and of `Ahmed` is for GXT 2

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to have key/value in a SimpleComboBox is to use a ListStore with type BaseModel. BaseModel allows you to save data as key/value like following:

```
SimpleComboBox combo = new SimpleComboBox();
ListStore<BaseModel> store = new ListStore<BaseModel>();

combo.setStore(store);
combo.setDisplayField("name");
// complete the SimpleComboBox properties here.

// Now, we will create data sample for the answer
BaseModel model = new BaseModel();
model.set("id", 1);
model.set("name", "Java");
store.add(model);

BaseModel model = new BaseModel();
model.set("id", 2);
model.set("name", "PHP");
store.add(model);
```

as you can see from the code snippet, BaseModel stores data as key/value pairs, so you can easily get the selected element from the SimpleComboBox like:

```
BaseModel selectedModel = (BaseModel) combo.getValue();
String techName = selectedModel.get("name"); // return value of key name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// MySimpleComboBox extends SimpleComboBox
public MySimpleComboBox(){
    super(new ListStore<Person>(new ModelKeyProvider<Person>() {
        @Override
        public String getKey(Person item) {
            return item.id();
        }
    }), new LabelProvider<Person>() {
        @Override
        public String getLabel(Person item) {
            return item.toString();
        }
    });
}
```

I did that once I think it is what your looking for (or what you were looking for).